# Ionic 4 *ngFor does not scroll properly in iOS

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I have a popover with ion-content. That content is replicated over a *ngFor with a maximum height of the ion-content to 400px. When the new content is added (from a user search) the scroll doesn't work properly on iOS. See below:

Chrome and Safari on my computer (working correctly):

[image]

On iOS, it is not setting the scroll area properly, same code. What you will see is I try to scroll to see the bottom of the list, but it bounces back up each time as if I were at the bottom of my content:

[image]

I tried putting it in an ion-list as well, I don't really want to do that though. It didn't work either.

Here is the HTML (scrollable is verified true, get-user-location class just sets max height to 400px):

```
<ion-content [scrollY]="scrollable" class="get-user-location">
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <h5 padding no-margin *ngIf="message">{{ message }}</h5>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input
        color="primary"
        (keyup.enter)="searchClicked()"
        formControlName="search"
      ></ion-input>
      <ion-button (click)="searchClicked()" fill="clear"
        ><ion-icon onclick="searchClicked()" name="search" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon
      ></ion-button>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="searchStatus">
      {{ searchStatus }}
    </ion-item>

    <ion-radio-group formControlName="radio" (ionSelect)="radioSelected($event)">
      <ion-item *ngFor="let searchResult of searchResults; let i = index">
        <ion-radio mode="md" value="{{ i }}" margin-end></ion-radio>
        <ion-label>{{ searchResult!.name }}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-radio mode="md" value="city" margin-end></ion-radio>
        <ion-label>Default city listed below</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-radio-group>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-select
        okText="Okay"
        cancelText="Dismiss"
        formControlName="city"
        (ionChange)="cityChanged($event)"
      >
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city.id">
          {{ city.name }}
        </ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-button
      *ngIf="showSubmit"
      (click)="dismiss()"
      [disabled]="!form.valid"
      fill="clear"
      class="button-padding-start large"
      margin
      >Submit</ion-button
    >
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16910

Remove ion-content and add this to your component's scss:

```
.backdrop-no-scroll ion-content {
  --overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<ion-content no-bounce has-bouncing="false">
...
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried it. That doesn't work. The issue is the content size to be scrolled isn't updating. So it's not the issue that it's bouncing. It's that it thinks it has reached the end of the content, so it bounces. But there is more content which was dynamically created.

Comment: so have you got solution?

Comment: Nah... just an issue. I have a feeling it's an actual bug in Ionic or Capacitor. I'll post one there if I don't get it resolved.

Comment: Found the solution... posted it

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if it's a ionic bug on iOS, there are multiple ways to "resolve" the issue.

---

(*recommended*) **First**:
Add a couple of empty ion-item at the end of the list with the property lines="none" 
(`<ion-item lines="none"></ion-item>`)

(*I do not recommend*) **Second**:
Set `no-bounce has-bouncing="false"` to the ion-content

(*I do not recommend*) **Third**:
Remove ion content and add to the CSS file 
`.backdrop-no-scroll ion-content { --overflow: hidden; }`